# Getting an association count with elixir and phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to find how many teams belong to a league in my application. I can't seem to find an answer to this question. Here our my models:

#### League.ex

```
defmodule Statcasters.League do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "leagues" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :teams, Statcasters.Teams.Team
    belongs_to :user, Statcasters.Coherence.User
end
```

#### Team.ex

```
defmodule Statcasters.Teams.Team do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Statcasters.Teams.Team

  schema "teams" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :league, Statcasters.League
    belongs_to :user, Statcasters.Coherence.User

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

I'm trying to find how many teams a particular league has. If this were Rails I'd do this `League.first.teams.count`. How can I do this with Elixir, Phoenix and Ecto?

I'm an Ecto noob but here is my first attempt that does not work.

```
  def league_limit(league) do
    count = from l in league,
      left_join: t in assoc(l, :teams),
      group_by: l.id,
      select: {l, count(t.id)}
  end
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the code you posted?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `Team` should not belong to `User` explicitly, it brings a potential inconsistency, since it already belongs to `League` and the latter already belongs to `User`.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right, but the league should not belong to user. I'm in the process of creating a join table users_leagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find how many teams a particular league has.

Assuming the `league` argument to `league_limit` is a loaded `%League{}` struct, add a `where:` clause to narrow it down to the league you pass in:

```
 def league_limit(league) do
    count = 
      from l in League,
      where: l.id == ^league.id,
      left_join: t in assoc(l, :teams),
      group_by: l.id,
      select: {l, count(t.id)}
  end
```